# How to save gedit changes right along with nano changes, instead of appending ~?

Tags: nano, gedit

I've got a `.nanorc` file that I love, records all changes to files when using nano. Gedit, on the other hand, just writes out a file next to the live version with a ~ appended. Is there some bit of magic that would process the changes through nano, so that I have an organized situation? Thank you so much.

```
# using gedit checkbox to save backups :(
______________________
$ ls
.notes
.notes~
wallet
wallet~
______________________
# $HOME/.nanorc
set smooth
set linenumbers

include "/usr/share/nano/asm.nanorc"
include "/usr/share/nano/css.nanorc"
# ... another couple dozen language specific files...

set autoindent
set backup
set backupdir "/home/self/.nano-backups"
set historylog
set morespace
set nowrap
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
set mouse
______________________
$ ls .nano-backups
'!home!self!.bash_aliases~.30'
'!home!self!.bash_aliases~.31'
'!home!self!.bash_aliases~.32'

# and so on :) I love it.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate a bit on what _process the changes through nano, so that I have an organized situation_ means?

Comment: Sort of--- do the same changes in nano on close, and thus they appear in the nanobackups directory? Kind of a lot to ask?